# hashcat - toggle-case dictionary attack (case sensitive)

Tags: linux, cracking, hashcat

I'm new to computer security but I'm trying the same to make a **toggle case attack** starting from a dictionary password.

I read [there](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=toggle_case_attack) that it's possible to **alternate uppercase and lower case word** starting from a dictionary to have all combinations (case sensitive).

I don't know what command to use and 4 now I'm stopped on standard dictionary attack

```
sudo hashcat -m 16800 convertedpcap.16800 dict.txt
```

Someone knows howto?

Here the complete help (I removed - [ Hash modes ] - to preserve space):

```
kali@kali:~$ hashcat --help
hashcat - advanced password recovery

Usage: hashcat [options]... hash|hashfile|hccapxfile [dictionary|mask|directory]...

- [ Options ] -

 Options Short / Long           | Type | Description                                          | Example
================================+======+======================================================+=======================
 -m, --hash-type                | Num  | Hash-type, see references below                      | -m 1000
 -a, --attack-mode              | Num  | Attack-mode, see references below                    | -a 3
 -V, --version                  |      | Print version                                        |
 -h, --help                     |      | Print help                                           |
     --quiet                    |      | Suppress output                                      |
     --hex-charset              |      | Assume charset is given in hex                       |
     --hex-salt                 |      | Assume salt is given in hex                          |
     --hex-wordlist             |      | Assume words in wordlist are given in hex            |
     --force                    |      | Ignore warnings                                      |
     --status                   |      | Enable automatic update of the status screen         |
     --status-timer             | Num  | Sets seconds between status screen updates to X      | --status-timer=1
     --stdin-timeout-abort      | Num  | Abort if there is no input from stdin for X seconds  | --stdin-timeout-abort=300
     --machine-readable         |      | Display the status view in a machine-readable format |
     --keep-guessing            |      | Keep guessing the hash after it has been cracked     |
     --self-test-disable        |      | Disable self-test functionality on startup           |
     --loopback                 |      | Add new plains to induct directory                   |
     --markov-hcstat2           | File | Specify hcstat2 file to use                          | --markov-hcstat2=my.hcstat2
     --markov-disable           |      | Disables markov-chains, emulates classic brute-force |
     --markov-classic           |      | Enables classic markov-chains, no per-position       |
 -t, --markov-threshold         | Num  | Threshold X when to stop accepting new markov-chains | -t 50
     --runtime                  | Num  | Abort session after X seconds of runtime             | --runtime=10
     --session                  | Str  | Define specific session name                         | --session=mysession
     --restore                  |      | Restore session from --session                       |
     --restore-disable          |      | Do not write restore file                            |
     --restore-file-path        | File | Specific path to restore file                        | --restore-file-path=x.restore
 -o, --outfile                  | File | Define outfile for recovered hash                    | -o outfile.txt
     --outfile-format           | Num  | Define outfile-format X for recovered hash           | --outfile-format=7
     --outfile-autohex-disable  |      | Disable the use of $HEX[] in output plains           |                                                           
     --outfile-check-timer      | Num  | Sets seconds between outfile checks to X             | --outfile-check=30                                        
     --wordlist-autohex-disable |      | Disable the conversion of $HEX[] from the wordlist   |                                                           
 -p, --separator                | Char | Separator char for hashlists and outfile             | -p :                                                      
     --stdout                   |      | Do not crack a hash, instead print candidates only   |                                                           
     --show                     |      | Compare hashlist with potfile; show cracked hashes   |                                                           
     --left                     |      | Compare hashlist with potfile; show uncracked hashes |                                                           
     --username                 |      | Enable ignoring of usernames in hashfile             |                                                           
     --remove                   |      | Enable removal of hashes once they are cracked       |                                                           
     --remove-timer             | Num  | Update input hash file each X seconds                | --remove-timer=30                                         
     --potfile-disable          |      | Do not write potfile                                 |                                                           
     --potfile-path             | File | Specific path to potfile                             | --potfile-path=my.pot                                     
     --encoding-from            | Code | Force internal wordlist encoding from X              | --encoding-from=iso-8859-15                               
     --encoding-to              | Code | Force internal wordlist encoding to X                | --encoding-to=utf-32le                                    
     --debug-mode               | Num  | Defines the debug mode (hybrid only by using rules)  | --debug-mode=4                                            
     --debug-file               | File | Output file for debugging rules                      | --debug-file=good.log                                     
     --induction-dir            | Dir  | Specify the induction directory to use for loopback  | --induction=inducts                                       
     --outfile-check-dir        | Dir  | Specify the outfile directory to monitor for plains  | --outfile-check-dir=x                                     
     --logfile-disable          |      | Disable the logfile                                  |                                                           
     --hccapx-message-pair      | Num  | Load only message pairs from hccapx matching X       | --hccapx-message-pair=2                                   
     --nonce-error-corrections  | Num  | The BF size range to replace AP's nonce last bytes   | --nonce-error-corrections=16                              
     --keyboard-layout-mapping  | File | Keyboard layout mapping table for special hash-modes | --keyb=german.hckmap                                      
     --truecrypt-keyfiles       | File | Keyfiles to use, separated with commas               | --truecrypt-keyf=x.png                                    
     --veracrypt-keyfiles       | File | Keyfiles to use, separated with commas               | --veracrypt-keyf=x.txt                                    
     --veracrypt-pim            | Num  | VeraCrypt personal iterations multiplier             | --veracrypt-pim=1000                                      
 -b, --benchmark                |      | Run benchmark of selected hash-modes                 |                                                           
     --benchmark-all            |      | Run benchmark of all hash-modes (requires -b)        |                                                           
     --speed-only               |      | Return expected speed of the attack, then quit       |                                                           
     --progress-only            |      | Return ideal progress step size and time to process  |                                                           
 -c, --segment-size             | Num  | Sets size in MB to cache from the wordfile to X      | -c 32                                                     
     --bitmap-min               | Num  | Sets minimum bits allowed for bitmaps to X           | --bitmap-min=24                                           
     --bitmap-max               | Num  | Sets maximum bits allowed for bitmaps to X           | --bitmap-max=24                                           
     --cpu-affinity             | Str  | Locks to CPU devices, separated with commas          | --cpu-affinity=1,2,3                                      
     --example-hashes           |      | Show an example hash for each hash-mode              |                                                           
 -I, --opencl-info              |      | Show info about detected OpenCL platforms/devices    | -I                                                        
     --opencl-platforms         | Str  | OpenCL platforms to use, separated with commas       | --opencl-platforms=2                                      
 -d, --opencl-devices           | Str  | OpenCL devices to use, separated with commas         | -d 1                                                      
 -D, --opencl-device-types      | Str  | OpenCL device-types to use, separated with commas    | -D 1                                                      
     --opencl-vector-width      | Num  | Manually override OpenCL vector-width to X           | --opencl-vector=4
 -O, --optimized-kernel-enable  |      | Enable optimized kernels (limits password length)    |
 -w, --workload-profile         | Num  | Enable a specific workload profile, see pool below   | -w 3
 -n, --kernel-accel             | Num  | Manual workload tuning, set outerloop step size to X | -n 64
 -u, --kernel-loops             | Num  | Manual workload tuning, set innerloop step size to X | -u 256
 -T, --kernel-threads           | Num  | Manual workload tuning, set thread count to X        | -T 64
     --spin-damp                | Num  | Use CPU for device synchronization, in percent       | --spin-damp=50
     --hwmon-disable            |      | Disable temperature and fanspeed reads and triggers  |
     --hwmon-temp-abort         | Num  | Abort if temperature reaches X degrees Celsius       | --hwmon-temp-abort=100
     --scrypt-tmto              | Num  | Manually override TMTO value for scrypt to X         | --scrypt-tmto=3
 -s, --skip                     | Num  | Skip X words from the start                          | -s 1000000
 -l, --limit                    | Num  | Limit X words from the start + skipped words         | -l 1000000
     --keyspace                 |      | Show keyspace base:mod values and quit               |
 -j, --rule-left                | Rule | Single rule applied to each word from left wordlist  | -j 'c'
 -k, --rule-right               | Rule | Single rule applied to each word from right wordlist | -k '^-'
 -r, --rules-file               | File | Multiple rules applied to each word from wordlists   | -r rules/best64.rule
 -g, --generate-rules           | Num  | Generate X random rules                              | -g 10000
     --generate-rules-func-min  | Num  | Force min X functions per rule                       |
     --generate-rules-func-max  | Num  | Force max X functions per rule                       |
     --generate-rules-seed      | Num  | Force RNG seed set to X                              |
 -1, --custom-charset1          | CS   | User-defined charset ?1                              | -1 ?l?d?u
 -2, --custom-charset2          | CS   | User-defined charset ?2                              | -2 ?l?d?s
 -3, --custom-charset3          | CS   | User-defined charset ?3                              |
 -4, --custom-charset4          | CS   | User-defined charset ?4                              |
 -i, --increment                |      | Enable mask increment mode                           |
     --increment-min            | Num  | Start mask incrementing at X                         | --increment-min=4
     --increment-max            | Num  | Stop mask incrementing at X                          | --increment-max=8
 -S, --slow-candidates          |      | Enable slower (but advanced) candidate generators    |
     --brain-server             |      | Enable brain server                                  |
 -z, --brain-client             |      | Enable brain client, activates -S                    |
     --brain-client-features    | Num  | Define brain client features, see below              | --brain-client-features=3
     --brain-host               | Str  | Brain server host (IP or domain)                     | --brain-host=127.0.0.1
     --brain-port               | Port | Brain server port                                    | --brain-port=13743
     --brain-password           | Str  | Brain server authentication password                 | --brain-password=bZfhCvGUSjRq
     --brain-session            | Hex  | Overrides automatically calculated brain session     | --brain-session=0x2ae611db
     --brain-session-whitelist  | Hex  | Allow given sessions only, separated with commas     | --brain-session-whitelist=0x2ae611db

- [ Brain Client Features ] -

  # | Features
 ===+========
  1 | Send hashed passwords
  2 | Send attack positions
  3 | Send hashed passwords and attack positions

- [ Outfile Formats ] -

  # | Format
 ===+========
  1 | hash[:salt]
  2 | plain
  3 | hash[:salt]:plain
  4 | hex_plain
  5 | hash[:salt]:hex_plain
  6 | plain:hex_plain
  7 | hash[:salt]:plain:hex_plain
  8 | crackpos
  9 | hash[:salt]:crack_pos
 10 | plain:crack_pos
 11 | hash[:salt]:plain:crack_pos
 12 | hex_plain:crack_pos
 13 | hash[:salt]:hex_plain:crack_pos
 14 | plain:hex_plain:crack_pos
 15 | hash[:salt]:plain:hex_plain:crack_pos

- [ Rule Debugging Modes ] -

  # | Format
 ===+========
  1 | Finding-Rule
  2 | Original-Word
  3 | Original-Word:Finding-Rule
  4 | Original-Word:Finding-Rule:Processed-Word

- [ Attack Modes ] -

  # | Mode
 ===+======
  0 | Straight
  1 | Combination
  3 | Brute-force
  6 | Hybrid Wordlist + Mask
  7 | Hybrid Mask + Wordlist

- [ Built-in Charsets ] -

  ? | Charset
 ===+=========
  l | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
  u | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
  d | 0123456789
  h | 0123456789abcdef
  H | 0123456789ABCDEF
  s |  !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
  a | ?l?u?d?s
  b | 0x00 - 0xff

- [ OpenCL Device Types ] -

  # | Device Type
 ===+=============
  1 | CPU
  2 | GPU
  3 | FPGA, DSP, Co-Processor

- [ Workload Profiles ] -

  # | Performance | Runtime | Power Consumption | Desktop Impact
 ===+=============+=========+===================+=================
  1 | Low         |   2 ms  | Low               | Minimal
  2 | Default     |  12 ms  | Economic          | Noticeable
  3 | High        |  96 ms  | High              | Unresponsive
  4 | Nightmare   | 480 ms  | Insane            | Headless

- [ Basic Examples ] -

  Attack-          | Hash- |
  Mode             | Type  | Example command
 ==================+=======+==================================================================
  Wordlist         | $P$   | hashcat -a 0 -m 400 example400.hash example.dict
  Wordlist + Rules | MD5   | hashcat -a 0 -m 0 example0.hash example.dict -r rules/best64.rule
  Brute-Force      | MD5   | hashcat -a 3 -m 0 example0.hash ?a?a?a?a?a?a
  Combinator       | MD5   | hashcat -a 1 -m 0 example0.hash example.dict example.dict

If you still have no idea what just happened, try the following pages:

* https://hashcat.net/wiki/#howtos_videos_papers_articles_etc_in_the_wild
* https://hashcat.net/faq/
kali@kali:~$
```

Thankz

Comment: Short answer under ⬇️ by *Andrew Zick* solved all and runned works 4 me. Go ahead and read what he's wrote. Also his demo explains in detail what the reader is searching. Example centered that added to my file is a bomb: * "include[s] all possible toggle-case switches of the plaintext positions 1 to 15 of...5 characters at once"*. Good Man. Justice about this software Is done! ✅

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about haxoring, not programming.

Comment: Robert Columbia "I’m voting to close this question because it is about haxoring, not programming." you can vote down all you want but i've done a bash script that use this command. So i think it's programming. by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Short answer:

Download [toggle5.rule](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/blob/master/rules/toggles5.rule) from the Hashcat repo on Github and try running this:

```
sudo hashcat -m 16800 -r toggle5.rule convertedpcap.16800 dict.txt
```

---

### Explanation of hashcat rules + a demo:

That older togglecase example links to a [newer article](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=toggle_attack_with_rules) recommending rules be used, specifically the examples in [rules/](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/tree/master/rules). For this example, let's use [toggle5.rule](https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/blob/master/rules/toggles5.rule), which the site explains "include[s] all possible toggle-case switches of the plaintext positions 1 to 15 of...5 characters at once".

Let's try cracking the md5 of the string `HaShCaT` and put that in our `example.hash` file (it's `41e24266141b6ef98bf0e1fb54b238a1`) and use a dictionary of just the string `hashcat` for `example.dict` file. Go ahead and create these two files in whatever folder you're working in, with whatever editor you prefer.

If we just use a normal dictionary attack, like so:

```
hashcat -a 0 -m 0 example.hash example.dict
```

It fails to crack the hash. No surprises there. Now add the `--stdout` flag.

```
hashcat --stdout -a 0 -m 0 -r toggle5.rule example.dict
```

You will see the hash printed followed by all candidates that would be tried if we were trying to crack a hash, which in this case is just the string `hashcat`. Note, no need for example.hash in the command when using `--stdout`.

---

Now let's try adding the toggle5.rule into the mix with

```
hashcat --stdout -a 0 -m 0 -r toggle5.rule example.dict
```

I've copied the rule directly from the Github repository. Thanks to `--stdout` this should print a **lot** of variations on `hashcat`. We can make it a bit more manageable by piping it into `less` or better yet...

```
hashcat --stdout -a 0 -m 0 -r toggle5.rule example.dict | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

Basically this will display the number of times each variation of `hashcat` would be generated as a candidate. Now you can see how a rule generates new candidates for trying to crack hashes! And with that, the final run...

```
hashcat -a 0 -m 0 -r toggle5.rule example.hash example.dict
```

And success! It cracks the md5 hash `HaShCaT`.

---

### Now about your question...

Speaking specifically to what you asked about, you might not need all the variations that `toggle5.rule` gives. If you know for certain that the password you're trying to crack is less that 15 characters or it won't have more than 4 uppercase characters, you can cut down on the variations.

For example, if you only wanted to try candidates with alternating cases for every letter, your rule file would just be

```
T0T2T4T6T8TATCTE
T1T2T5T7T9TBTDTF
```

Reusing `hashcat` as the example, this would generate the candidates `HaShCaT` and `hAsHcAt`. Just in case this is closer to what you're looking for. Feel free to describe your specific scenario in a comment and we can work together on what rules might make the most sense.

Comment: Andrew Zick I'm free to comment your method with explanation about using `sudo hashcat -m 16800 -r toggle5.rule convertedpcap.16800 dict.txt`to crack the md5 hashcat with dictionary is what I'm searching for. I note that gives out all strings in uppercase and lowercase variations (like HaShCaT and hashcat). About my question I have to say that's resolved xfecly. You've also done example calculating the md5 `41e24266141b6ef98bf0e1fb54b238a1` of hashcat. I think that by now I use forever the options `-a 0` and `--stdout` when cracking. You wrote like D'Annunzio! Write a guide about. accepted ✔️

Comment: Andrew Zick just a specification about my question and your explanation. "If you know for certain that the password you're trying to crack is less that 15 characters or it won't have more than 4 uppercase characters, you can cut down on the variations." -> this is a surplus of what I asked and the alternating cases fo. every letter is not specifically what I'm finding (`T0T2T4T6T8TATCTE` and `T1T2T5T7T9TBTDTF`). I'ts what I'm looking for. `sudo hashcat --stdout -a 0 -m 16800 -r toggle5.rule convertedpcap.16800 dict.txt`. That's only my command. Works  Compliments & tanks again 4 explanation.

Comment: Andrew Zick noteworthy also the pipe that manages and filters results `| sort | uniq -c | sort -rn` to manage the pipe`. A Lession 4 me 

Comment: All switched of the plaintext positions 1 to 15 of...5 for all characters done at once! 44000 ~ trys and hash cracked. New knowledge!

Comment: P.P.S. "**Download** toggle5.rule from the Hashcat repo on **Github** and try running this" --> **Github** solves all questions!

Comment: @ServerOverflowerManofDeath I had to google D'Annunzio and I'm flattered, glad that this answer was helpful for you!

Comment: ServerOverflowerManofDeath says that D'Annunzio and google are incompatible! I have been glad and flattered the same for your exposition! Helpful! <3